# How to get an iframe fullscreen on Safari IOS 16+

Tags: ios, iframe, safari, fullscreen

I have tried the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
    <title>Game Embed</title>
    <style>
        /* Added style */
        html, body, iframe, canvas, div {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        body {
            overflow: auto;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            background-color: #002B50;
        }

        #gameframe {
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: -webkit-fill-available;
            border: none;
        }

        #startButton {
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #000;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="startButton">Play Game</button>
    <iframe id="gameframe" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; camera; focus-without-user-activation *; monetization; gamepad; keyboard-map *; xr-spatial-tracking; clipboard-write; web-share" name="gameFrame" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-orientation-lock allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-presentation allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-downloads" src="" title="Game"></iframe>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
            this.style.display = 'none';
            const gameframe = document.getElementById('gameframe');
            gameframe.style.display = 'block';
            gameframe.src = "https://7252203e-60a1-4698-bba2-5a5327175ce7.poki-gdn.com/ce839146-34c2-401e-8ebf-ac88d456b234/poki-savegame-safarisavegame.html?next=https%3A%2F%2F7252203e-60a1-4698-bba2-5a5327175ce7.poki-gdn.com%2Fce839146-34c2-401e-8ebf-ac88d456b234%2Findex.html%3Fcountry%3DTH%26ccpaApplies%3D0%26url_referrer%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fpoki.com%252F%26tag%3Dpg-v3.118.0%26site_id%3D3%26iso_lang%3Den%26poki_url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fpoki.com%252Fen%252Fg%252Fstick-defenders%26gdhoist%3Dyes%26nonPersonalized%3Dn%26familyFriendly%3Dn%26categories%3D37%252C69%252C77%252C927%252C929%252C1140%252C1155%26special_condition%3Dlanding%26game_id%3D7252203e-60a1-4698-bba2-5a5327175ce7%26game_version_id%3Dce839146-34c2-401e-8ebf-ac88d456b234";

            // iOS Fix: Resizing for fullscreen and considering nav bar
            const resize = () => {
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                document.body.style.width = document.documentElement.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
                document.body.style.height = document.documentElement.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
            };
            window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
            resize();
            setTimeout(resize, 3000); // Additional attempt to resize after a delay for iOS
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

On my fully updated iphone 12 mini using Safari I cant get the game to go fullscreen.

I expected the game to go fullscreen like on https://poki.com/en/g/stick-defenders. Ideally I want a most basic example of how to get an external iframe to go fullscreen on IOS/Safari.